# Enabling Salesforce API Integration permission set issue

Tags: api, user, permission-sets

I added a new user for API integration purpose, i gave him **Salesforce Integration licence** and  the default **Salesforce API Only System Integrations** profile (Following the principle of least privilege)

I assigned this new user to the default permission set licence **Salesforce API Integration permission set licence**,

The issue i have is when i attempt to Enable the **Salesforce API Integration permission set licence** using **Enable for integrations** button,
[image: Issue screenshot]
i receive this error:

```
Platform Integration User can't be assigned the Salesforce API Integration permission set license, because Platform Integration User's user license doesn't support it.
```

After inspecting, i think the enabling process is assigning this permission set licence to Admin users (which they are already assigned to Salesforce platform licence).

Can any one guide me to how to solve this issue ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your created user's license type is "Salesforce Integration" or "Salesforce Platform"?